# About sigma algebra

Tags: statistics

Suppose that the sample space $S$ of some experiment
is finite. Show that the collection of all subsets of $S$ satisfies
the three conditions required to be called the collection of
events.

Maybe the three conditions are related in borel field.

Comment: Are you asking how to show that the power set is a sigma algebra?