# About event in sample space

Tags: statistics

> Suppose that the sample space $S$  of some experiment is finite. Show that the collection of all subsets of $S$ satisfies the three conditions required to be called the collection of events.

This problem is in *'Probability and Statistics' 4th. by degroot. exercise $1.4.12$.*

Comment: duplicated: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344186/about-sigma-algebra